# Redux-Saga - TakeEvery miss catch event

Tags: redux-saga

I have a strange problem with redux-saga. This is my code:

```
export default function* root() {
  yield [
    fork(analyticsSaga)
  ];
}

export function* analyticsSaga() {
  yield takeEvery([ANALYTICS_EVENT], callAnalyticsSession);
}
```

My use case is very simple. I have a product pagination page. Every time my products change, I dispatch an "ENALYTICS_EVENT". AnalyticsSaga is called only for the first 2 events.

Comment: The snippet you put here works fine. callAnalyticsSession is called every time i dispatch the ANALYTICS_EVENT action. Are you absolutely sure the action is dispatched more than twice? Do you use any other sagas? What other redux middlewares do you have in your app?

Comment: I dispatch multiple actions, I'm sure.
In my root saga I have other forks and I do not have any other middleware.
I do not know. It takes only the first two actions. : (

Comment: Is it a project you can share e.g. on github? I don't think I can help without seeing more of your code.

Comment: No sorry, I can't :(

Comment: Alright, I would double check you are not experiencing one of the two problems mentioned here https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html . If nothing else helps you can always do some step by step debugging in dev. tools to figure out what exactly is/isnt happening.